# How can I run mariadb and phpmyadmin podman containers and access my database from phpmyadmin?

Tags: centos, database, container, phpmyadmin, podman

I want to run database on CentOS Stream system using podman containers and access it with phpmyadmin that is running on another container. I created my mariadb container using this command:

```
podman run \
 --name mariadb0 \
 -p 3306:3306 \
 -v /var/www/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql:Z \
 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
 -d docker.io/library/mariadb
```

I can reach the database but I struggle to create phpmyadmin container which could be used to access my database. I don't know how to solve this. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You mention that you can reach the database container yourself, but you do not say what issues you have when trying to connect with a phpmyadmin container.  Showing how you are making the phpmyadmin container could help, plus any errors or messages you are getting when you try to connect to the database container.

Comment: Maybe you could put both containers in the same pod? This [blog post](https://www.linuxwave.info/2020/12/installing-wordpress-using-podman.html) shows an example of how to put a Mysql container and a Wordpress container  in a pod .

Answer (score 1):

I managed to connect to the database from phpmyadmin.

Create pod:

```
podman pod create \
 --name db0 \
 --publish 8080:80 \
 --publish 3306:3306
```

Run database:

```
podman run --name mariadb0 \
 --pod db0 \
 -v /var/www/mariadb0:/var/lib/mysql:Z \
 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="pass" \
 -e MYSQL_USER=name \
 -e MYSQL_PASSWORD="123" \
 -d docker.io/library/mariadb
```

Run phpmyadmin:

```
podman run --name phpmyadmin0 \
 --pod db0 \
 -d \
 -v /var/www/phpmyadmin0:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php:Z \
 -e PMA_HOST=127.0.0.1 \
 -e PMA_PORT=3306 \
 phpmyadmin
```

My question lacked some explanation, thanks for helping me out.